# Determine Nullity of $C$ Given Elements of Solution Space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Let C be a 3-by-5 matrix. The linear system $Cx = b$ has solutions for $b_1= \begin{bmatrix}
    2  \\
    1  \\
    1  \\
    \end{bmatrix}, b_2=\begin{bmatrix}
    1  \\
    0  \\
    3  \\
    \end{bmatrix}$, and does NOT have solutions for $b_3=\begin{bmatrix}
    3  \\
    0  \\
    2  \\
    \end{bmatrix}$ Determine the nullity of $C$.

Given that $b_1$ is a solution, I determined that the rank of of $C$ is $3$, since if you were to augment the reduced row echelon form of $C$ with $b_1$, you would need a leading $1$ in each of the $3$ rows otherwise you would get a contradiction of $0$ equaling a constant. On the other hand, $3$ is the highest possible number for the rank of $C$.

I believe that my error is somewhere is that reasoning above, as the rank of $C$ would be all that I need to then solve for the nullity, but the answer is incorrect. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rank is the dimension of the image.  Since $b_1$ and $b_2$ are independent, the image has dimension at least two.  On the other hand the image doesn't have dimension three, since $b_3$ isn't in it.

Thus the rank of $C$ is $2$.  So the nullity is...

Comment: How can we be sure that there isn't some other *b* which is not listed for which C *does* have a solution? Can we assume that the question implies that those are the only 3 possible solutions?

Comment: $T_C:\Bbb F^5\to\Bbb F^3$.  If the image had dimension three, it would be the whole $\Bbb F^3$.